# how to get XML attribute using XmlSerializer in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this class and xml file which i am using to get the values.

### XML file

```
<Task>
  <Employee Id="123">
    <string>/Name</string>
    <string>/Company</string>
  </Employee>

  <Manager Id="456">
    <string>/Name</string>
    <string>/Company</string>
  </Manager>
</Task>
```

### Code

```
public class Task
{
    public List<string> Employee;
    public List<string> Manager;
}

var taks = (Task)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Task)).Deserialize(streamReader);
```

so, in *tasks* i am getting list of *Employee* with Name and Compnay as values correctly. I want to get the Id for each element. how do i get it?

/Name and /Company can be anything. I can put any value in there and I get it in employee without even creating a property for it. same goes for Manager as well, I can have /Email, /Website, /LastLogin etc and I get it in the Manager object without even creating a property for it.

appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `Task` class as follows:

```
public class Task
{
    public Employee Employee;
    public Manager Manager;
}
```

Where `Employee` is:

```
public class Employee
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string Company{get;set;}
}
```

And `Manager` is:

```
public class Manager
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}

    public string Company{get;set;}
}
```

If you're interested in a generic list of properties for `Employee` and/or `Manager`, then consider having another class called `Property` as the following:

```
public class Property
{
     [XmlAttribute]
     public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

Then, change your `Manager` and `Employee` as the following:

```
public class Employee
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    public List<Property> Properties {get;set;}
}

public class Manager
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id {get;set;}

    public List<Property> Properties {get;set;}
}
```

Finally, change your XML as the following:

```
<Task>
  <Employee Id="123">
    <Properties>
       <Property Value="/Name" />
       <Property Value="/Company"/>
    </Properties>
  </Employee>

  <Manager Id="456">
    <Properties>
       <Property Value="/Name" />
       <Property Value="/Company"/>
    </Properties>
  </Manager>
</Task>
```

Comment: sorry, I should have explained it better. /Name and /Company can be anything. I can put any value in there and i get it in employee without even creating a property for it.

Comment: Is your XML fixed or you can change it?

Comment: I can change it anyway i want. I could have any value in there

Comment: I tried your exact solution. it picks up Id but does not pickup values.  any idea?

Comment: Ok i got it.... I need to change the <string>/Name</streing> to <task>/Name</task> and put <XmlElement> attribute ...thanks for your help